# Using 3 Buttons in PyQt5 DialogButtonBox

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm attempting to create a Login System type dialog box for practice using PyQt5 (I'm quite new to the module) and i'm trying to give the user the ability to click (Ok, Cancel, Apply) as the buttons underneath inputs boxes for Username / Password, but i'm not sure how I can actually get the apply button to work. I have `buttons.accepted.connect(*method*)` and `buttons.rejected.connect(*method*)` but I don't know how to specify the pressing of the accept button. I have tried using `buttons.clicked(dlgButtons[0]` (Which is where the button is stored) but it just gives me an error.

The code below is my declaration of the buttons if that helps. Thanks

```
buttons = qt.QDialogButtonBox()
        dlgButtons = (qt.QDialogButtonBox.Apply, qt.QDialogButtonBox.Ok, qt.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        buttons.setStandardButtons(
        dlgButtons[0] | dlgButtons[1] | dlgButtons[2]
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution might look like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class ModelessDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, part, threshold, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Baseline")
        self.setGeometry(800, 275, 300, 200)
        self.part = part
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.threshNew = 4.4
        
        label    = QLabel("Part            : {}\nThreshold   : {}".format(
                                                self.part, self.threshold))
        self.label2 = QLabel("ThreshNew : {:,.2f}".format(self.threshNew))
        
        self.spinBox = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(-2.3)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(99)
        self.spinBox.setValue(self.threshNew)
        self.spinBox.setSingleStep(0.02)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChang)
        
        buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(
            QDialogButtonBox.Ok 
            | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
            | QDialogButtonBox.Apply)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()            
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(self.label2)
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        layout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.resize(300, 200)  
        self.setLayout(layout)                                 

        okBtn = buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Ok) 
        okBtn.clicked.connect(self._okBtn)

        cancelBtn = buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        cancelBtn.clicked.connect(self.reject)   

        applyBtn = buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Apply)       # +++
        applyBtn.clicked.connect(self._apply)                     # +++

    def _apply(self):                                             # +++
        print('Hello Apply')    

    def _okBtn(self):
        print("""
            Part      : {}
            Threshold : {}
            ThreshNew : {:,.2f}""".format(
                self.part, self.threshold, self.spinBox.value()))
        
    def valueChang(self):
        self.label2.setText("ThreshNew : {:,.2f}".format(self.spinBox.value()))
        

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        label  = QLabel('Hello Dialog', self)
        button = QPushButton('Open Dialog', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(label)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)        

    def showDialog(self):
        self.dialog = ModelessDialog(2, 55.77, self)
        self.dialog.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.resize(300, 200)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: But the problem is I don't know how to assign a function to the apply button, and i'm quite new to this module and can't really tell where you have done that.
EDIT: Nevermind, i'm just an idiot and didn't see that I could scroll down, ignore me and thank you for the answer

Comment: @Nyaywraith  I marked the lines for you `# +++`

Answer (score 0):

What you are storing in the `dlgButtons` is just a list of *enums*, specifically the [`StandardButton`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#StandardButton-enum) enum, which is a list of *identifiers* for the buttons, they are not the "actual" buttons.

Also, you cannot use the `clicked` signal like this:

```
 buttons.clicked(dlgButtons[0])
```

That will generate a crash, as signals are not callable. The argument of the `clicked()` signal is what will be *received* from the slot, which means that if you connect a function to that signal, the function will receive the clicked button:

```
        buttons.clicked.connect(self.buttonsClicked)

    def buttonsClicked(self, button):
        print(button.text())
```

The above will print the text of the clicked button (Ok, Apply, Cancel, or their equivalent localized text).

What you're looking for is to connect to the clicked signals of the actual buttons, and you can get the individual reference to each button by using the [`button()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#button) function:

```
applyButton = buttons.button(qt.QDialogButtonBox.Apply)
applyButton.clicked.connect(self.applyFunction)
```